# como ordenar um array de objetos dentro de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript

eu tenho os seguintes dados:

```
[
  {
    "titulo": "Livro",
    "descricao": "descricao do livro 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "nome do livro 1",
            "paginas": 223,
            "lido": true,
        }
    ],
  },
  {
    "titulo": "Trilogia 1",
    "descricao": "descricao da trilogia 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "livro 1"
            "paginas": 219,
            "lido": true,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 2"
            "paginas": 242,
            "lido": false,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 3"
            "paginas": 331,
            "lido": false,
        }
    ],
  }
]
```

O que eu tô tentando fazer e não consegui é: ordenar a ordem dos titulos de acordo com o livro lido, caso alguma info do livro tiver lido === false, esse livro nao lido tem que ta no topo, entao neste caso, o **Livro** tem que vir por ultimo e a **Trilogia** em primeiro, porque ela tem informaçoes falsas na *info*, e na info ordenar tbm da mesma forma, os objetos de **lido == false** sempre no topo

Tentei utilizar reduce, map + filter mas nao consegui chegar em um resultado do tipo, essa parte de ordenar tão especificamente me confundiu

Comment: Porque usou  `map` e `filter`? Essas funções não fazem isso. A função correta é `sort`, e essa permite utilizar callback.

Comment: é que no caso eu precisava iterar pelo array *info* de cada objeto pra encontrar se existe lido === false e ordenar para o topo da lista

Comment: por favor, inclua seu código que de tentativa de ordenar. Recomendo também que leia o [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561), principalmente a seção [Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/13561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um callback no método `Array.sort`. Esta aceita um `callback`. Nesse `callback` podemos retornar `1`, `0` ou `-1`. `-1` muda a posição do item para a primeira, `1` para a final, e `0` mantém na mesma posição.

Veja um exemplo curto:

```js
livros.sort(function (livro) {
    livro.info.sort(function (item) {
        return item.lido ? 1 : -1;
    })
    
})
```

```js
var livros = [
  {
    "titulo": "Livro",
    "descricao": "descricao do livro 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "nome do livro 1",
            "paginas": 223,
            "lido": true,
        }
    ],
  },
  {
    "titulo": "Trilogia 1",
    "descricao": "descricao da trilogia 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "livro 1",
            "paginas": 219,
            "lido": true,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 2",
            "paginas": 242,
            "lido": false,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 3",
            "paginas": 331,
            "lido": false,
        }
    ],
  }
];


livros.sort(function (livro) {
    livro.info.sort(function (item) {
       return item.lido ? 1 : -1;
    })
   
})

console.log(livros)
```

Como o `sort` faz parte do `Array` de origem, então apliquei o `sort` no `Array` interno.

A pergunta também diz que, com o segundo item tem não-lidos, então precisa aplicar o `sort` também no Array principal.

Veja:

```js
livros.sort(function (livro) {
    livro.info.sort(function (item) {
        return item.lido ? 1 : -1;
    })
    
    return livro.info.some(function (item) {
        return item.lido === false;
    }) ? -1 : 1;
    
})
```

```js
var livros = [
  {
    "titulo": "Livro",
    "descricao": "descricao do livro 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "nome do livro 1",
            "paginas": 223,
            "lido": true,
        }
    ],
  },
  {
    "titulo": "Trilogia 1",
    "descricao": "descricao da trilogia 1",
    "info": [
        {
            "nome": "livro 1",
            "paginas": 219,
            "lido": true,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 2",
            "paginas": 242,
            "lido": false,
        },
        {
            "nome": "livro 3",
            "paginas": 331,
            "lido": false,
        }
    ],
  }
];


livros.sort(function (livro) {
    livro.info.sort(function (item) {
       return item.lido ? 1 : -1;
    })
    
    return livro.info.some(function (item) {
        return item.lido === false;
    }) ? -1 : 1;
   
})

console.log(livros)
```

A função `some` retorna `true` se qualquer item do `array` for avaliado como verdadeiro. No caso, o se um dos `item.lido` for avaliado como `false`, aplicamos um `-1`.

Comment: aaaa era isso mesmo, fiquei travado nisso, valeu demais agora entendi melhor essa função!!